# Chart.js: Change height of tooltip

Tags: chart.js, tooltip, height

I've got a callback for adding custom tooltip info:

```
options: {
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              // return a list of 10-50 lines of text
            }
          }
        }
                    }
}
```

but the height of the tooltip popup is too short, it isn't dynamically scaling to the length of the text newlines.

How do I fix this? Either auto-sizing the tooltip, or changing the height manually, forcing me to figure out a way to auto-size myself?

Comment: "10-50 lines of text" isn't a tooltip. You might be better off having a separate element close to the chart that displays this text on hover.

Comment: hmm, I ended up using the external tooltip feature, where you basically provide your own element with whatever you want inside, though I can't select and copy the info inside it so I might try popping up a jquery-ui dialog in the external tooltip call